# How can I solve endog valueerror in python?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have a problem, I try to do the logistic regression of a problem but it throws an error saying "endog must be in the unit interval.", I don't know what to do.

Please help and thanks in advance.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv(r"Datos.csv",index_col=0)
df.head()
Xtrain=df[['Intercepto','th','n','API','%S','EFC','BET']]
ytrain=df[['Ec']]
reg_mo=sm.Logit(Xtrain,ytrain).fit()
```

So the error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_21196/895908693.py in <module>
----> 1 reg_mo=sm.Logit(Xtrain,ytrain).fit()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, check_rank, **kwargs)
    463         if not issubclass(self.__class__, MultinomialModel):
    464             if not np.all((self.endog >= 0) & (self.endog <= 1)):
--> 465                 raise ValueError("endog must be in the unit interval.")
    466 
    467             if (not self._continuous_ok and

ValueError: endog must be in the unit interval.
```

Can u help me please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: endog must be in the unit interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322370/valueerror-endog-must-be-in-the-unit-interval)